# How to make my BS sidenav be on the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bit of a newbie question, so I apologise. Currently, this sidenav is to the left, how could I make it be to the right instead?

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  top: 52px;
  left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #27CD70;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="sidebar-toggle">
   <ul class="sidebar-nav">
       <li>
          <a href="#item1">Item 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="#item2">Item 2</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="#item3">Item 3</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
" float:right; "
```

or start giving it a left margin. That should do the trick.